# Folder Structure with Bootstrap

Tags: php, html

I have a very simple web development project I'm working on that uses php and bootstrap, nothing fancy.  I'm trying to organize my files but I'm quite ignorant of standards.  I was originally developing in an very old school (ie:dysfunctional) way like this:

> |---index.php
>   |
>   |---pages/
>   |       |---~php files here (example: photos.php, videos.php)
>   |       |---~folder for media here  (example: dogs_01.png, cats_01.png)
>   |
>   |---css/
>   |---js/

but now I'm trying out a different system where I put the media in one folder instead of in a folder next to the files (so I'm trying to separate all the media assets from all the markup, from the fonts, the css, etc...like this:

> |---index.php
>   |
>   |---_/
>   |       |---css/
>   |       |---js/
>   |       |---fonts/
>   |       |---images/
>   |       |---video/
>   |       |---inc/
>   |
>   |---php files here (example: photos.php, videos.php)

But now it seems like my root folder is getting packed with php files and getting kind of crazy.  I'm considering adding a:

> |---index.php
>   |
>   |---_/
>   |       |---css/
>   |       |---js/
>   |       |---fonts/
>   |       |---images/
>   |       |---video/
>   |       |---inc/
>   |       |---pages/php files here (example: photos.php, videos.php)

Honestly, I just don't know how to organize my files.  How do people organize regular websites these days?  I'm just confused about file structure and need some advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a *right* way to organize your files.

Patterns such as MVC used in modern PHP frameworks make the separation of files a lot easier, but even this isn't a silver bullet. As a developer who has worked on plenty of other people's code, I'd at least like to see files organized by some sort of functionality. If you have config files, put them in a **config** folder. If you have various helper libraries, put them in a **library** folder. Even with procedural PHP, you can have some semblance of MVC style separation by putting your view related code into a **views** folder for example.

You might get some good ideas by taking a look at [this tutorial by Derek Reynolds](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/organize-your-next-php-project-the-right-way--net-5873) (2009) that talks about some of the "best practices" for organizing procedural code.

At a minimum, keep your server-side code separate from your public code. This allows you to set access rules on your protected folder to at least make it a little more difficult to perform a [directory traversal attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I'm looking into zend structure for regular stuff and angular for single page web apps.  Very difficult but guess this is the way to go.